# Track values of model over time in Django

Tags: django

I'm building a Django application, and I would like to track certain model statistics over time (such as the number of registered users or the number of times a page has been edited). Is there a predetermined app that would do this for me, or would it be easier to roll one from scratch?

At the end of the day, I'm looking for something that can track unique values across different models over time.

Comment: I dont really understand what you are looking to do, or the implications - but to track different values across models, you can just create your own unique field instead of the automatically assigned a candidate key. That could be a slugfield, and has `app-name-model-id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number of registered users is already available:

```
active_users = User.objects.filter(is_active=True).count()
```

for all active and inactive users it's just

```
active_users = User.objects.count()
```

To get the number of times a page has been edited, there are a couple of approaches: you could track and record each individual change (and count them) or just override the save method for the model to provide a counter of sorts.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.counter += 1
```

If you want to record each individual change, use a versioning tool like django-reversion (it is under active development and a ton of deployments).

Answer (score 0):

You could use [django-reversion](https://github.com/etianen/django-reversion) for audit trail.